# extracting Field dependency metadata using SOQL etc

Tags: soql, dependent-picklist, field-dependencies

We are migrating from salesforce to another system. We need to build field dependencies for dependent picklist fields in salesforce in the new system as well. Can we extract field dependencies from salesforce using some SOQL or any other method which can be provided to external system.
\n
\n

For Example we have custom fields for Country > State > City which are dependent picklist fields on custom object and many of such fields do not use global value set. We need to extract such data and provide it to external system. We are exploring ways to do the same.

Comment: How is your field dependency defined in Salesforce? Are you referring to picklists in general or other fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the Dependency API. Check out this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vuj4Vcti-Z4 or here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_metadatacomponentdependency.htm

Comment: This seems to be about component dependencies, e.g. "this layout is dependant on this custom field". I dont think this covers dependant picklist values?